# Unable to create Azure App Service from the Free Services menu

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-free-services

This is something that should just work but when I try to create an App Service from the [Azure Free Services](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/FreeServicesBlade)  it fails with the following message

> Cannot create selected service now
>   Please try again in a few minutes.

I have followed this advice and tried again in a few minutes, but it doesn't work.

Has anyone else had this issue before and is it possible to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure is under [capacity restrictions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/) during March and April of 2020 owing to the covid-19 epidemic. If it were necessary to deprioritise particular services, free tier apps would likely be among those chosen to be suspended.

Comment: Cheers for that, it's unfortunate but understandable. It would be great to see something that specifies that some Free Services aren't available for the moment.

Comment: I got the same answer and link from Azure Support on Twitter